# How would I add a state constructor to this js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set state for the value for a search input in order to test if the state goes through. My ultimate goal is to build a search filter, to filter through the array of cryptocurrency data by using the name of the currency. However in order to do this, I must first make sure that I know who to pass state to the value for the search input.

How would I add this constructor

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this: {
      [x: string]: 'test',
      any:any,
      search: string
    },
  }
```

to this file:

```
import React  from 'react'
import { withRouteData, Link } from 'react-static'

//


export default withRouteData(({ currencies }) => (
  <div>

    <Link to="/markets/quoinex">Quoinex</Link>
        <Link to="/markets/qryptos"><b>Qryptos</b></Link>
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="BTC etc."/>
          <input className="sub" type="submit" value={this.state.search} />
        </form>

    <h1>Tokens</h1>
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Crypto/Token</th>
            <th>Min Withdrawal Qty</th>
            <th>Min Order Qty</th>
        </tr>

        {currencies.slice(0,52).map(currency => (
             <tr key={currency.currency}>
             <td>{currency.currency}</td>
             <td>{currency.minimum_withdrawal}</td>
             <td>{currency.minimum_order_quantity}</td> 
         </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
    <table className="table2">
        <tr>
            <th>Crypto/Token</th>
            <th>Min Withdrawal Qty</th>
            <th>Min Order Qty</th>
        </tr>

        {currencies.slice(52,).map(currency => (
             <tr key={currency.currency}>
             <td>{currency.currency}</td>
             <td>{currency.minimum_withdrawal}</td>
             <td>{currency.minimum_order_quantity}</td> 
         </tr>
      ))}
    </table>


  </div>
))
```

Comment: You cannot have state in functional components.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best illustrated by example; functional components can't have state: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/259554/

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        test: 'this is a test'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}, {this.state.test}</div>
  }
}

const FunctionalHello = ({name}) => (
    <div>Hello {name}</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <Hello name="World" />
    <FunctionalHello name="World" />
    </div>,

  document.getElementById('container')
);
```